# Key Manager in High Availability Mode

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are configuring an API Manager distributed setup with 2 Key manager nodes. Key Manager nodes are fronted by F5 Load Balancer. Key Manager is used only for authentication purpose. We are using PING Federate server for Authorization.

We are getting an error as "Error! Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized" when user log in to the Publisher sometimes. We noted that two services are calling when log in to the publisher and the issue is getting since those two services calling from the same session are redirected to the two key manager nodes.

What are the configurations we need to do when using two key manager nodes? How can we fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist session in F5 for WSO2 Key manager servers. There aren't any configurations in WSO2 server side. Enabling session affinity in F5 will work.

Example config for Nginx using JsessionId - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer#HA-Publisher